# Prevent symlink path in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a location path in ngx.conf. I want to prevent any symlinks path from being downloaded.

My nginx path

location ~ ^/home/(.*) $ {

}

now all files are getting downloaded from the path. And i want to prevent symlinks from download.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/home/(.*) $ {
    disable_symlinks on;
    ...
}
```

Comment: disable_symlinks directive not found. Any other way

Comment: This directive appeared in version 1.1.15. Is your NGINX really that old?